# Win2d UWP fluid animation canvas line

Tags: c#, uwp, line, win2d

I have to get a fluid animation of a line drawn with Win2d. Below is the code that simulates my problem.

MainPage.xaml:

```
     <canvas:CanvasAnimatedControl x:Name="animatedControl" 
                                   Margin="0,30,0,0"
                                   Height="500"
                                   Draw="OnDraw"/>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    private void OnDraw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        CanvasDrawingSession ds = args.DrawingSession;

        double height = sender.Size.Height;
        double width = sender.Size.Width;

        Random random = new Random();

        double pointHeigth = random.Next(0, 300);

        var point1 = new Vector2((float)(width / 2), (float)height);
        var point2 = new Vector2((float)(width / 2), (float)height - (float)pointHeigth);

        CanvasSolidColorBrush brush = new CanvasSolidColorBrush(sender, Colors.Green);

        ds.DrawLine(point1, point2, brush, (float)10);
    }
```

In this way I get a flounce animation how can I get a smooth animation of the line?

I state that I have to use the canvas with win2d.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE (My code that doesn't work)

```
    private Vector2 _point1;
    private Vector2 _point2;
    private Vector2 _targetPoint;
    private TimeSpan _animationElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnDraw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        CanvasDrawingSession ds = args.DrawingSession;

        double height = sender.Size.Height;
        double width = sender.Size.Width;


        Random random = new Random();

        double pointHeigth = random.Next(0, 300);

        var _point1 = new Vector2((float)(width / 2), (float)height);

        var _point2 = new Vector2((float)(width / 2), (float)height - (float)pointHeigth);

        CanvasSolidColorBrush brush = new CanvasSolidColorBrush(sender, Colors.Green);

        ds.DrawLine(_point1, _point2, brush, (float)10);
    }

    private Vector2 Tween(Vector2 sourcePoint, Vector2 targetPoint, float percentage)
    {
        return new Vector2(targetPoint.X + (targetPoint.X - sourcePoint.X) * percentage, targetPoint.Y + (targetPoint.Y - sourcePoint.Y) * percentage);
    }

    private void OnUpdate(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedUpdateEventArgs args)
    {
        _animationElapsedTime += args.Timing.ElapsedTime;
        var percentage = Math.Min(_animationElapsedTime.TotalSeconds / 5.0f, 1f);
        _point2 = Tween(_point1, _targetPoint, (float)percentage);
    }
```

UPDATE 2 MyCode:

```
    double previuosData = 0;
    bool isDraw = false;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnDraw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        if (isDraw)
            return;

        CanvasDrawingSession ds = args.DrawingSession;

        double height = sender.Size.Height;
        double width = sender.Size.Width;

        CanvasSolidColorBrush brush = new CanvasSolidColorBrush(sender, Colors.Green);

        Random random = new Random();

        double pointHeigth = random.Next(0, 500);

        var point1 = new Vector2((float)(width / 2), (float)height);

        if (pointHeigth > previuosData)
        {
            for (double a = previuosData; a <= pointHeigth; a++)
            {
                isDraw = true;
                var point2 = new Vector2((float)(width / 2), (float)height - (float)a);
                ds.DrawLine(point1, point2, brush, (float)10);
            }
            isDraw = false;
        }
        else
        {
            for (double a = previuosData; a >= pointHeigth; a--)
            {
                isDraw = true;
                var point2 = new Vector2((float)(width / 2), (float)height - (float)a);
                ds.DrawLine(point1, point2, brush, (float)10);
            }
            isDraw = false;
        }

        previuosData = pointHeigth;
    }
```

in this way I make the animation a little more fluid but with the for loop it's not enough how could I improve?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Random and that generates a random number from the given range in each single frame. So it means 60 times per second the second point will jump randomly up and down.

Compare to something like the following:

```
private bool _adding = true;
private int _currentHeightOffset = 0;
private void OnDraw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
{
    CanvasDrawingSession ds = args.DrawingSession;

    double height = sender.Size.Height;
    double width = sender.Size.Width;

    var point1 = new Vector2((float)(width / 2), (float)height);
    var point2 = new Vector2((float)(width / 2), (float)height - (float)_currentHeight);

    CanvasSolidColorBrush brush = new CanvasSolidColorBrush(sender, Colors.Green);

    ds.DrawLine(point1, point2, brush, (float)10);
    if (_adding)
    {
       _currentHeightOffset++;
    }
    else
    {
       _currentHeightOffset--;
    }
    if (_currentHeightOffset == 0 || _currentHeightOffset == 300 )
    {
       _adding = !_adding;
    }        
}
```

Now in this example, I am moving the point pixel by pixel in each frame until it reaches 300 and then go back to 0. So the result should be a line which appears to be fixed in `point1` and moving and stretching up and down.

The key is, that the values are no longer random, but predictable from frame to frame.

### Update

As I discussed in comments, you could do "tweening" effect between two points.

We would use the following method:

```
private Vector2 Tween(Vector2 sourcePoint, Vector2 targetPoint, float percentage)
{
   return new Vector2( 
       targetPoint.X + (targetPoint.X - sourcePoint.X)*percentage,
       targetPoint.Y + (targetPoint.Y - sourcePoint.Y)*percentage)  
}
```

Now if you want to animate between these two points for 5 seconds, you could do something like:

```
private Vector2 _point2;
private TimeSpan _animationElapsedTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

private void OnUpdate(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, 
      Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedUpdateEventArgs args)
{
    _animationElapsedTime += args.Timing.ElapsedTime;
    var percentage = Math.Min(_animationElapsedTime.TotalSeconds / 5.0f, 1f);
    _point2 = Tween(_point1, _targetPoint, percentage);
}
```

This is just a quick sketch of how the code would look like, however, it the important points - once you select the target point (using random for example), you need to decide how long do you want the animation to take and then move the second point closer and closer to the target until the time is over.

Comment: Random represents my real problem because it represents a band of an audio spectrum and behaves in the same way.

Comment: If you need to animate between one point and another, you just can't do the random calculation on each draw. Instead you will need to take calculate once and then move from the current point to the target across multiple updates.

Comment: And how can I do it to do it through multiple updates? thanks for your answer Martin

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example how such a operation would be done :-) . It is just example though, so you will have to edit it to match your scenario

Comment: Do you could kindly give the complete code? I can't get it to work ...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, I don't have my development PC at hand currently. But if you are facing some issue, update the question with additional answers or post the not working code.